# Sticky posts per category

Tags: terms, sticky-post

**I need:** to have the ability to set one post as sticky in one category and not the others.

**Example:** So let's say i have this three categories: *"one" "two" and "three".*
and i have a post named "sticky in one and two" and another post named *"sticky in one"*.

Now i want the "sticky in one and two" post to be sticky in the category *"one"* and in the category *"two"* but not in the category *"three"*.

And i want the *"sticky in one"* post to be sticky in the category *"one"* but not in the category *"two"* and not in the category *"three"*.

**Thoughts:** I thought of trying something like add a taxonomy with the same terms as the categories terms *("one","two","three")* and then to make two loops which in the first one i get the posts which have the name of the current category in there custom taxonomy terms (for example when i'm on the category *"one"* archive it will fetch only the posts that has *"one"* in this new custom taxonomy) and then a second loop which will get all the current category posts excluding the first loop posts. but it seem very complicated and i'm guessing one could think of a better way to do it, so please share your ideas...

Also a minor problem with this method is that i can check a term in the custom taxonomy which isn't marked in the categories taxonomy which could be confusing...

**Thanks!**

Comment: Nothing obvious leaps out.  We've recently got the ability to add meta data to taxonomy terms, but not to term *relationships* which is what would make this easy.  Perhaps you could store a list of post IDs in a term's metadata?

Comment: Thanks but i'm looking for a solution which will give the ability to easily mark a post as sticky in different categories from the admin panel.

Comment: Well, yes, you'd need to build the interface too.

Comment: You could also have a look at this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-sticky-post/

Comment: that's a nice plugin but he has the ability to set only one category and only one post per category.

Comment: Yes but you could see how he codes it for inspiration.